# recovery the values ckecked with checkbox

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the follow inputs type checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkboxes" value="3" name="mycheck">option1
<input type="checkboxes" value="4" name="mycheck">option2
<input type="checkboxes" value="2" name="mycheck">option3
<input type="checkboxes" value="6" name="mycheck">option4
```

Also , I have a button and a select dropdown.

I print the inputs checked with this code:

```
foreach ( $_POST as $checkbox=>$value ) {
echo $value.'<br>';
}
```

but also print the value for button, and value for dropdown, I only want that print the input type checkbox checked.  Someone know what is my error?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
foreach ( $_POST['mycheck'] as $checkbox=>$value ) {
echo $value.'
';
```